# Having a sequence integer for record in scope of foreign key

Tags: postgresql

Imagine I have a table containing columns `user_id`, `sequence_id`
The task is to have `sequence_id` incremented by one for each record in a scope of `user_id`.

For example

```
user_id  | sequence_id
1        | 1
2        | 1
```

If new record inserted with `user_id` 1 it should have `sequence_id` 2

Now, one possible approach I see is to lock table for writing, take the last sequence_id for user_id and increment it, insert and then unlock the table.

I wonder is there any other approach to this task, thinking about triggers.

Comment: You don't need to lock the entire table, just the rows with a specific `user_id` value.

Comment: @mustaccio Can you specify the lock type